# Kotlin lazy var throwing ClassCastException: kotlin.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE

Tags: kotlin

I've reached the hair pulling out stage with this one!  I have a lazy var declared in a Kotlin data class.  It is a Boolean and calculates it's value based on other fields in the class.

The way that the `Lazy.kt` implementation works is to creat an anonymous object called `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` to use as the basis of determining whether or not the lazy var has been initialized.  Each lazy var instance will have its own unique instance of `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE`.  This object is stored in the `_value` field of the Lazy object.

When the value of the lazy var is accessed a check is made to see whether the current value matches the `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` by doing a reference comparison.  If not, then the initializer is called to create the value which is the stored in the lazy var `_value` field.

What appears to be happening in my case is that the `UNINITALIZED_VALUE` object is being created and assigned to the value during the lazy var creation - so far so good.  However, when I attempt to retrieve the value, inexplicably, the `UNITIALIZED_VALUE` object has somehow been set to a different object value to the one originally stored in the `_value` field and so the comparison fails, the lazy implementation thinks the value has been set and so attempts to cast the `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` object to a `Boolean` and boom!  Exception!

What's really weird is that I am the only person in the team experiencing this issue - I have deleted and reinstalled everything - Android Studio, full git clone, gradle cache, emulators.  I can't think of anything else and am unable to see the `UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` object being set twice with the debugger.

Comment: Does the decompiled code make sense? The decompiler is at Tooks -> Kotlin -> Bytecode (this could possibly help)

Comment: Concurrency issue? kotlinc messing up? We're gonna need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Comment: Could you find the problem? It happened to me when my Spark job tried to access lazy attribute.